# why can't a structure have more than one property of type "text"

Tags: bixby

[image: oxoi]

[image]

This doesn't seem right. Why can't a structure have more than one property per type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE error message is valid.

Due to the design of Bixby platform (modeling and action planing requires unique concept type), a structure can have at most 1 concept of each type. (The concept could be `max(Many)` for an array)

One general rule is to name each of your concept and not directly use any core base type. It might seems unnecessary at the beginning, but soon it will start making sense and making things easier for complex capsules.

To fix above error, create a Text type BixbyUserId, and replace with:

```
property (bixbyuserid) {
 type (BixbyUserId) 
 min (Optional) max (One) 
}
```